# 404 before playing video

Tags: ionic3, angular4-router

My template:

```
<iframe [src]="videourl" width="500" height="100%"></iframe>
```

My class:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
Video:any;
constructor(private domSanitizer : DomSanitizer) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.videourl= this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(myvideourl)
}
```

It is working fine but the issue is while playing the video before i am getting this type error: (platform-browser.es5.js:2899 GET http://localhost:8100/null 404 (Not Found) ie it is indicating a error 404 page and then it is playing the video

Comment: does the error print _during play_ or _before play_?

Comment: before playing video

Comment: your url isnt set yet perhaps when view is loaded.. either set in constructor or use an `*ngIf` in `video` tag

Comment: <div *ngIf="videoURL !=''; then truthyTemplate else falsyTemplate"></div>
  <ng-template #truthyTemplate>
   <iframe width="560" height="315" [src]="videoURL" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #falsyTemplate>
   <img class="well_image" src="{{image}}" />
  </ng-template>

Comment: can u make any correction with that  code

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially on how to write a good title. Right now your title makes it impossible to get any information about your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can handle it. This error will  accrue when low network bandwidth.

**Import this dependency.**

```
import { SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Loading, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

You keep your video global.

playListVideos:**SafeResourceUr**[ ]=[ ];

```
          videoUrls:string[]=[
            'https:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'https:Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'https:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'https:Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
          ];
trustedLoading:Loading;
```

**Write your construcor**

```
constructor(
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
  }
```

**handle your video loading**

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    for(let index = 0; index < this.videoUrls.length; index++){
      this.playListVideos.push(this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.videoUrls[index]));
    }
    this.trustedLoading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content:'Please wait...'
    });
    this.trustedLoading.present();
  }
  handleVideoLoad(){
    if(this.trustedLoading){
      this.trustedLoading.dismiss();
      this.trustedLoading = null;
    }
  }
```

**Add it in your html**

```
<iframe width="100%" height="315" *ngFor="let playList of playListVideos"
        [src]="playList ? playList : null" (load)="playList ? handleVideoLoad() : null" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have tried it same process but before video play, it showed the same error. Error is web page is not available, the web page at file:///android_asset/www/null could not be loaded because net:::err_file_not_foun

Comment: Are you mean your app is automatically close or broken?

Comment: No, the error page is getting and after few milliseconds video is playing

Comment: <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />

Comment: I think this is not a  loading problem, maybe sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl problem, why because before loading and after page navigate it should be shown error. @EDISON J

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe [attr.src]="videourl" width="500" height="100%"></iframe>
```

By using `domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` we can mention `[attr.src]`

add attr.src at place of src in iframe

Comment: Formatting issues aside, it's unclear what you mean with your answer. Please add details why this would solve the OP's issue.